# 0x1e BSOD during Win 7 Installation

Tags: windows, bsod, reinstall

http://www.imgur.com/pRd6H.jpg

I just took out the old OS drive, popped in a new one and went for a fresh install. 3 times I've gotten this BSOD trying to install windows, and I don't even know where to start. Any words of wisdom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.faultwire.com/solutions-fatal_error/Check-to-be-sure-you-have-adequate-disk-space-0x0000001E-*1045.html) post may be helpful...

It's known that two basic things are being the cause of stop 0x1e. One is the free disc space which is not your case since you're trying to do a clean installation. Two is the BIOS low level drivers mismatch with O.S. itself. It would be a solution if you'll be able to update the BIOS itself, if there is an updated version out there of course.

Me also had the same problem when i was upgrading win7 from winXp. Clean Xp installations were working but not any attemps of win7. So, i was able to find a consistent up-to-date BIOS and updating the BIOS itself solved the problem.

Comment: Your comment caused a click in my head. I disabled the marvel RAID controller, and it seems to be going fine for now. Will see if it continues being stable.